# Unable to reassign value in a while loop in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, while-loop

I am trying to get the response from a socket connection. I am using a while loop to read the bytes into a string. I declare a variable "response" to save the response to, but I am unable to access the variable outside of the while loop.

```
try {
            socket = Socket()
            socket.connect(InetSocketAddress(IP, PORT))
            val out = DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
            val dataIn = DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
            out.writeBytes(sending)
            var ByteIn: Byte
            response = ""
            ByteIn = dataIn.readByte()


            while (true) {
                response += ByteIn.toChar()
                ByteIn = dataIn.readByte()
                Log.d("Response response", response)// I am able to get the response in the loop
                Log.d("ByteIn Byte In", ByteIn.toString())
            }
            Log.d("Response response", response) //I am unable to get the response here
//close the try block and catch various exceptions
```

I am able to get the response in the loop, But I am unable to get the response after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared two response variables that one is in while scope and the other in the try scope.

Comment: the declaration is before the try catch block, it was only assigned an empty string before the while loop and assigned the response in the while loop

Comment: In doubt try to define the variable outside both scopes and see if changes the behaviour. Or use breakpoints to check the variables valued along the flow of work.